# How to correct wrong timezone offset in pytz and django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz

I am writing a project with django.

I am using timezone 'Asia/ShangHai', when I am getting the datetime object, the offset of the timezone is incorrect and was:

```
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>
```

And the offset should be +8:00:00
AFAICR, the problem was not there before.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should show the line that creates the `datetime` object. Mention what are `USE_TZ` (it should be `True`),  `TIME_ZONE` (the default timezone), and the current timezone (activated by `django.utils.timezone.activate()`).

Comment: This is apparently a known pytz bug: https://answers.launchpad.net/pytz/+question/186082. This pytz FAQ may help: https://answers.launchpad.net/pytz/+faq/1.

Comment: @evergreen: it is not a bug. [`pytz` docs say at the  top that `localize()` should be used](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). Anyway, if you use django's timezone API then you don't need to know `pytz` API i.e., it is enough to be familiar with one API (django or pytz).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: The bug I was referring to was that pytz has an incorrect offset for the Asia/Shanghai time zone, as the OP noticed. Maybe typo is a better description than bug. You are correct about the docs saying that localize() should be used. That's why I referenced the FAQ.

Comment: @evergreen again, there is no bug. pytz has the correct info for the timezone (there are multiple UTC offsets at different dates). OP uses the library incorrectly—wrong UTC offset is chosen. The FAQ as well as the docs say how it should be used (to get the correct UTC offset).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Understood. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: So the problem is that pytz has the right offset, but when we use datetime.replace, error is going to occur. So we need to use tz.localize()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function with django:

```
def add_local_tz_to_native_time(native_dt):
  # type: (datetime.datetime) -> datetime.datetime
  from django.utils import timezone

  if timezone.pytz is None:
    return native_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone())
  else:
    return timezone.get_current_timezone().localize(native_dt)
```